# Similar to Eclipse Resource bundle editor in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: encoding, utf-8, intellij-idea, resourcebundle

I just begin use IDEA and I can't belive that in IDEA doesn't have smth similar. I want to add property in Resource Bundle editor for all files difference just locale suffix and that words after ediiting on other language become in UTF-8 encoding.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has a very good, [built-in editor for resource bundles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resource-bundle.html), as well as [full I18N support](https://web.archive.org/web/20140903130603/http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/i18n_support.html). See (from official help):

[image: Bundle editor]

and:

[image: Completion]

Comment: What about getting in `FontChooser_ru=/u7867/u2353`

Comment: @Ray: it's [supported by default](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-encoding-for-properties-files.html) and completely transparent to you.

Comment: @Ray: as far as I remember you are working with normal Unicode characters in editor and they are translated on-the-fly to `\u` escape sequences. When you open such file again, these escapes are translated back to normal characters. So it's painless. Try it yourself!

Comment: problem that it doesn't happen `they are translated on-the-fly to \u escape sequences.`  I change encoding project to default UTF, write word in russian, open file and get not UTF-8 symbols